# What is this foreign material on my outsourced PCB?

Tags: pcb, pcb-assembly

I had this board populated by an EMS house. There is foreign material around some of the pins. They don't know what it might be. Our collective best guess is that it is somehow shavings from the casing of the resistor network. The material does not appear to be conductive. It does not appear on every instance of this type of component on the board, but does appear on many boards in the same location.
[image]

Has anyone seen this before? Any ideas what it is, or how I can find out?

Comment: Looks like poorly cleaned flux residue to me.

Comment: @ConnorWolf  At first, I also thought that this a poorly cleaned flux (e.g. no-clean flux after aqueous wash).  But if that were the case, wouldn't we see this residue in more places?  The flux and wash are the same across the board.

Comment: Maybe those tall components are shadowing that particular area from the washer?

Comment: Perhaps some solvent in the flux used is stripping off part of the resistor array casing. It could be that one of the assemblers is using a different brand or type or one is just more sloppy on occasion with the application. Thus giving the varied results. You could test this with some alcohol or similar solvent and see if it removes the coating. But I like The Photon's idea better.

Comment: Flux washing is very much not a consistent across a PCB. You'll get eddies, and local clumps of crap unless you put a LOT of effort into cleaning around and under EVERY part.

Comment: So if it's flux residue, what will that mean for the operation of the board? Is that kind of contaminant conductive?

Comment: @StephenCollings Flux residue can sometimes be a problem in circuits that require very low leakage or in RF or very high speed circuitry. Depending on the type of flux it can cause long term corrosion issues. In many applications a small amount of flux residue isn't a problem, but you have to determine that based on the individual circuit, the type of flux, and the environment that the board will be in.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it is the case, but it could be oxidization due to lack of good cleaning and drying. I encountered same problem once.